# Using promises in my mean stack app

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous

I've created a controller that does a bing search based on the user's input into the url. Based on my results from doing a console.log the controller is working correctly and I have set that variable to return. In the route file the information is not displaying to the page. I thought it might be an asynchronous issue so I am trying to use promises to make sure the controller has returned before it tries to do the res.json but I'm not very familiar with promises so my syntax might be off or I might be going about this the wrong way. Will someone take a look at this syntax and see if there is an issue.Currently only an empty object is displaying on the page.

```
app.route('/imagesearch/:keyword')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        var resObj = [];
        resObj = new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(bingSearchHandler.findImages(req.params));
        });

        resObj.then(res.json(resObj));

    });

//BINGSEARCHHANDLER
'use strict';

var bingAPPID = 'fwHyQAoJMJYmK8L4a3dIV2GAEUfXAlFRjCnBx0YbfPE=';
var Search = require('bing.search');
var util = require('util');

var search = new Search(bingAPPID);

function bingSearchHandler () {

this.findImages = function(userInput){
    var keyword = userInput.keyword;
    search.images(keyword,
          {top: 10},
          function(err, results) {
            if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            else
                {
                    var resArr = [];
                  (util.inspect(results, 
                  {colors: true, depth: null})); 

                  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                    {
                        var tempObj = {};
                        tempObj.url = results[i].url;
                        tempObj.snippet = results[i].title;
                        tempObj.thumbnail = results[i].thumbnail.url;
                        tempObj.context = results[i].sourceUrl;

                        resArr.push(tempObj);
                    }
                    console.log(resArr);
                    return resArr;
                }
          }
        );
  }

}

module.exports = bingSearchHandler;
```

Comment: What does the bingSearchHandler.findImages function do? In general, nodejs has the following syntax for the functions ([args..], callback), the callback is the function to be called after the function you have called ends, as first parameter the callback should expect and error, and in the following arguments the result. Could you please show me the return of the findImages function so I can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this code? Here you have the bing.search documentation, https://www.npmjs.com/package/bing.search Always try to use callbacks instead of promises in NodeJs, remember that the first parameter of a callback is always the error (if there is any), then the response

```
app.route('/imagesearch/:keyword')
.get(function (req, res) {
    bingSearchHandler.findImages(req.params, function (err, response) {
      if (err) return res.status(400)

      res.json(response)
    })
});

//BINGSEARCHHANDLER
'use strict';

var bingAPPID = 'fwHyQAoJMJYmK8L4a3dIV2GAEUfXAlFRjCnBx0YbfPE=';
var Search = require('bing.search');
var util = require('util');

var search = new Search(bingAPPID);

function bingSearchHandler () {

this.findImages = function(userInput, callback){
    var keyword = userInput.keyword;
    search.images(keyword,
          {top: 10},
          function(err, results) {
            if(err) callback(err)
            else
                {
                    var resArr = [];
                  (util.inspect(results,
                  {colors: true, depth: null}));

                  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                    {
                        var tempObj = {};
                        tempObj.url = results[i].url;
                        tempObj.snippet = results[i].title;
                        tempObj.thumbnail = results[i].thumbnail.url;
                        tempObj.context = results[i].sourceUrl;

                        resArr.push(tempObj);
                    }
                    console.log(resArr);
                    return callback(null, resArr);
                }
          }
        );
  }

}

module.exports = bingSearchHandler;
```

Comment: Why should someone prefer callbacks over promises?

Comment: I just assumed he was right, but upon searching I can't find anything that supports the claim. I'll revert my answer to using promises as they're easier on the eyes imo.

Comment: You should prefer callbacks over promises  IN Nodejs, all the libraries in nodejs use callbacks, for example the bing library, mongoose, so all your functions should use callbacks in NodeJS. It's a good practice to use callbacks instead of promises in NodeJS, you could perfectly use promises in your Angular code @Dehli

Comment: Most libraries use callbacks, but i don't think you should base your coding styles on other libraries. I think it's just personal preference, especially now that Promises are natively supported in JavaScript. Also @TamasHegedus since he asked the question initially.

Comment: I am just saying that he should prefer callbacks in nodejs @Dehli, using promises you avoid the callback hell, but unfortunately most of the nodejs libraries use callbacks, and implementing promises in each one of the returns of those libraries would make the code harder to read for you and for the people who tries to help you when reading your code

Comment: @Dehli, Rodrigo: Guys, it looks like this question has much more in it to be answered in a comments section :) I think I will start a thread about it after some investigation. I prefer promises over callbacks, and I think all the libs use callbacks because of legacy reasons, but the only pros of promises on nodejs I could gather is avoiding the callback hell and _automatic error propagation_. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I agree @TamasHegedus :) Also Rodrigo, thanks for the discussion! I think if you look at my answer you will see how you could use callbacks along with promises. You shouldn't have to rewrite the libraries you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

**Using callbacks**

```
app.route('/imagesearch/:keyword')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        // Make the async request, pass the callback function
        bingSearchHandler.findImages(req.params, (error, response) => {
            if (error === null) {
                res.json(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Additionally, you'll need to rework your `findImages` function.

```
this.findImages = (userInput, callback) => {
    var keyword = userInput.keyword;
    search.images(keyword, {top: 10}, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            var resArr = [];
            util.inspect(results, {colors: true, depth: null}); 

            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var tempObj = {};
                tempObj.url = results[i].url;
                tempObj.snippet = results[i].title;
                tempObj.thumbnail = results[i].thumbnail.url;
                tempObj.context = results[i].sourceUrl;

                resArr.push(tempObj);
            }
            callback(null, resArr);
        }
   });
}
```

**Using promises**

```
app.route('/imagesearch/:keyword')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        // Make the async request, pass the callback function
        bingSearchHandler.findImages(req.params).then(response => 
            res.json(response);
        });
    });


// Images function
this.findImages = (userInput) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var keyword = userInput.keyword;
        search.images(keyword, {top: 10}, function (err, results) {
            if (err && typeof reject === 'function') {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                var resArr = [];
                util.inspect(results, {colors: true, depth: null}); 

                for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var tempObj = {};
                    tempObj.url = results[i].url;
                    tempObj.snippet = results[i].title;
                    tempObj.thumbnail = results[i].thumbnail.url;
                    tempObj.context = results[i].sourceUrl;

                    resArr.push(tempObj);
                }
                if (typeof resolve === 'function') {
                    resolve(resArr);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this but got 'cannot read property of undefined'. Undefined was what I was getting for resObj before which is why I thought I might need a promise to make sure bingSearchHandler returned it's results before I tried to send it to the page.

Comment: See my comment @RawleJuglal, NodeJS usually does not use promises it uses callbacks, if you could provide me the code of the findImages function I could help you

Comment: Promises should not be used in nodejs, instead use callbacks